# Fortran filling arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have 5 arrays defined as

```
Real, Allocatable :: ruvw(:,:,:)
Real, Allocatable, Dimension(13) :: a, b, c, d, e

Allocate (ruvw(13,5,2))
Allocate (a(13),b(13),c(13),d(13),e(13))
```

I am trying to fill ruvw using the other array in the following way

```
ruvw(:,:,1) = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

I am getting error

```
Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what the

```
 [a,b,c,d,e]
```

does is that it concatenates the 1D arrays in to a long one, it does not build a 2D one. You have to use `reshape([a,b,c,d,e], [13, 5] )` to get the 2D array out of it.